# How to make the Visual Studio Code Debug Console show its content?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying [a very basic piece of TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67150890/how-to-see-console-output-when-debugging-typescript-in-visual-studio-code), following the [Typescript in VS Code tutorial.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-tutorial)

The basic code:

```
let message: string = 'Hello World';
console.log(message);
```

is then run in a node.js server. And when it's finished, the tutorial says that the output should show in the *Debug Console* window:

[image]

Except in reality **nothing** shows up:

[image]

Not the command line:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk-17325 out\helloworld.js
```

Not the indication from **node** that it's running:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:17325/00fff82b-4f18-84c2-9a76eecd90dd
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

(I don't know if that UUID is important, i typed it out from the tutorial's screenshot as best i could).

Nor does it show:

> `Hello World`

### But *"Clearing"* the console causes it to not clear

After screaming, hitting my desk, scaring people, i discovered the *"Clear the Console"* [image] button:

[image]

And clicking the clear the empty console, causes the console to display stuff:

[image]

- Question 1: Why does *'clear the console'* do the opposite of clearing the console?
- Question 2: Why does *"clearing the console"* show the content i was waiting to see?
- Question 3: Where is the remaining text messages; such as the command line in the screenshot?

I also discovered that even though the console is empty, if i use the **Search** box:

[image]

And then search for anything:

[image]

and then blank the search filter out, the text appears:

[image]

- Question 5: Why didn't the text appear before?
- Question 6: Why did searching for something and then blanking it out make text appear?
- Question 7: Can i make it **always** show the text?

But the underlying, unifying question is:

> How can i make the <kbd>Debug Console</kbd> show what its supposed to show?

### Versions

- **TypeScript**: `1.55.2` *(Help → About)*
- **TSC**: `4.2.4` *(`tsc -version`)*
- **Node.js**: `v14.16.1` *(`node --version`)*

Comment: Exactly what versions of VSC, NodeJS, and TypeScript are you using? How was TypeScript installed (e.g. `npm` globally, npm locally, a non-local but IDE-specific installation? does anything appear in the Output or Terminal windows?)

Comment: @Dai Added to the question, with the steps i used to find them, in case they're wrong.